# Using PHP instead of JSON in jQuery instant search script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery which pulls results from the JSON BingAPI. How can I make my script pull content from a PHP script rather than the BingAPI?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var keyword=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=?&Appid=642636B8B26344A69F5FA5C22A629A163752DC6B&query='+keyword+'&sources=web';
        window.location.hash=keyword;

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"jsonp",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html('');
                if(response.SearchResponse.Web.Results.length){
                    $.each(response.SearchResponse.Web.Results, function(i,data){
                        var title=data.Title;
                        var dis=data.Description;
                        var url=data.Url;
                        var final="<div class='webresult'><div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+title+"</a></div><div class='desc'>"+dis+"</div><div class='url'>"+url+"</div></div>";
                        $("#result").append(final);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you still want to use Bing API for actual search or you're asking how to invoke your own custom script that does searches based on your own database? If you just want to be able to query something of your own, you change the URL, but if you want your PHP script to query the API of the 3rd party - you need to create a proxy PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var yt_url='http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=?&Appid=642636B8B26344A69F5FA5C22A629A163752DC6B&query='+keyword+'&sources=web';
```

With your json suggest url

```
var yt_url='http://yourwebsite/json.php?query='+keyword;
```

Comment: explain does not work, gosh. Also just see the output of bing json and compare with yours too see if there are any differences.

Comment: see the second part of my comment

Comment: look at the html. (view-source)

Comment: @callum yes you are right because they accept requests only coming from AJAX. Anyway the problem could be because you are outtputting the wrong json. You should see from the console if there are any errors

Comment: @callum: that's the problem! acutally on bing the file is called json.ajax because outputs json! :) not html. You should output json too. see json_encode();

Comment: @callum that's completly another question, and it was hard for me to get what was the error here (because in your first question you didn't write anything about it). Please open a new question for this.

Comment: You can either change your PHP script to output JSON instead of HTML as Bing does, or you can change your JavaScript to inject the HTML directly into the page instead of parsing JSON to create HTML itself.